# Error while Using docker behind proxy- TLS failed to parse certificate

Tags: docker

I am trying to run zeppelin using docker. I found one good github project for the same. My machine is behind the proxy and I have added http_proxy and https_proxy information in /etc/defaults/docker file also.

```
bala@axis-v4:~/Projects/docker-zeppelin$ sudo docker pull dylanmei/zeppelin
Using default tag: latest
Pulling repository docker.io/dylanmei/zeppelin
Error while pulling image: Get     
https://index.docker.io/v1/repositories/dylanmei/zeppelin/images: tls:  
failed to parse certificate from server: x509: unhandled critical extension
bala@axis-v4:~/Projects/docker-zeppelin$
```

Can anyone help to find out whats going wrong here?

Here is some more information

/etc/default/docker

```
export http_proxy=http://<username>:<password>@<proxy host IP>:3128
export https_proxy=https://<username>:<password>@<proxy host IP>:3128
HTTPS_PROXY=https://<username>:<password>@<proxy host IP>:3128
HTTP_PROXY=http://<username>:<password>@<proxy host IP>:3128
```

/etc/systemd/system/docker.service.d/http-proxy.conf

```
[Service]
Environment="HTTP_PROXY=http://<username>:<password>@<proxy host IP>:3128/"
Environment="NO_PROXY=localhost,127.0.0.0/8,40.221.94.62
```

Hope it helps

Comment: Please post here your configuration in `/etc/defaults/docker`

Comment: Are you sure this has to do with the proxy? The error message indicates there is a compatibility problem with the certificate. It contains a critical extension that is not understood by the client.

Comment: Looks like you need to update your certificates on your host, possibly adding a CA from a local web proxy if it's inspecting encrypted traffic on your network.

Comment: Hi BMitch, I did now sudo update-ca-certificates. But it did not help. I still see the same issue